# Does anyone know if webdriver-io can be used with AWS device farm ? How to set it up?

Tags: reactjs, webdriver-io, aws-device-farm

I am trying to setup e2e for my react apps using AWS Device Farm Browser Testing, I can see it supports selenium-remote-web-driver on documentation but I am interested on knowing if I can use webdriver-io and execute my tests on device farm ?

I can’t find a service runner available for device-farm ? Aren’t there any yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is just as any other cloud web and mobile testing platform like browserstack and saucelab, it is possible to do it.

Reference: https://kapoorlakshya.github.io/executing-webdriverio-browser-tests-aws-device-farm

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by another user this reference [example](https://kapoorlakshya.github.io/executing-webdriverio-browser-tests-aws-device-farm) looks very good. In AWS Device Farm Desktop Browser Testing documentation also there is one small example on how to configure web driver io. Check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/testing-frameworks-nodejs.html)